# Where will I be able to move out after Salesforce DEV career as programmer?

Tags: apex, lightning

So tomorrow im having second job interview in which I might get salesforce developer junior position(still learning). The company Im going to would help me with my lacking knowledge of software engineering with the help of trailheads and their programmers to learn SF.

So my question is, IF I'll get into salesforce development (apex,lightning,soql etc.) after couple of years of practice will I be able to go into more classical software development easily like java or c# and get those years in salesforce credited as *geniune developer not some admin which doesnt count as programmer*?

Comment: Start the trailheads before you start the job, would be my 2 cents. I learned from scratch when I started working with salesforce (before trailhead existed), but I had a prior development background. It still took a year or two before I was really proficient working with salesforce & the tools it offers. Theres a lot of stuff that salesforce does that is specific to salesforce, but the backbone of this CRM is the same as every other CRM (with some exceptions, like nosql stacks)

Answer (score 7):

Developing code is developing code. It doesn't matter if it's JavaScript or Java or C#. While it is true you'll possibly need to learn a new language, second and subsequent languages are easier than the first, because the ideas behind programming are more-or-less universal. If you learn LWC, you'll be able to almost directly translate that knowledge to other types of languages in the UI space, such as React, and knowledge of SOQL and Apex may well be useful for SQL and Java/C#/C++/etc. There are significant differences, to be sure, but having that experience will be useful.

Also, having technical knowledge is part of what you need to branch out to Project Lead/Business Analyst/etc, jobs that require technical knowledge, as well as communication, critical thinking, and problem-solving skills. Some of this you won't learn by being any kind of developer, but most of these skills are necessary as a developer, especially when working on complicated projects with a team.

It's also entirely possible that you'll never need to switch careers if you want to. I've been doing this for more than a decade (as a developer), and I expect to be able to continue on for many years to come. If Salesforce should happen to disappear, I can translate my skills to other systems and languages, but presuming it doesn't, I'd be perfectly happy doing this for the next few decades until I retire.